# Convert CSV table to MySQL and insert the content in phpmyadmin with Python through the browser

Tags: python, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a script that collects information and generates a CSV file with it.

I don't have remote access to MySQL via port 3306 released, I just have access to phpmyadmin through the browser using login and password.

The codes I've found apparently only work by directly accessing the database via 3306.

Would it be possible to convert the CSV file to MySQL embed code and open the browser, login and run the embed code via Python? (Chromedriver?)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In PHPMyadmin you can choose CSV format on "Import" tab.

[image]

Comment: In reality I would like to do this by running the code directly in SQL Query. But first I would need to convert the CSV into SQL code. Like a: INSERT IGNORE INTO table_name(id,description,name) VALUES (12345,'Seller','John');

Answer (score 0):

Yoy can use SQL command too... like below.
But in this case your Client need to have access to CSV file.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/<PATH TO YOUR FILE>/YOURS-CSV-FILE.csv' 
INTO TABLE `tabe_name` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS (`column1Name`,`column2Name`,`column3Name`,`column4Name`);
```

More in documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html